# Algorithm to schedule jobs to minimise change

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, scheduling, job-scheduling

I'm writing a program in Python that will hopefully minimise the tool changes to do with a CNC turret punch.

The information is stored in a big dictionary:

```
Data = {
  'job1' : {
    'tool1' : {'clearance' : X, 'station': Y, 'angle': Z, },
    'tool2' : ...
  },
  'job2' : ...
}
```

Jobs usually use between 4-8 tools, however there's a lot of tool use overlap between jobs (thus only requiring 1 or 2 changes between jobs).

I want to be able to input that I want to do job1, job3, job5, job7 and job8 and the program to sort the jobs into 'groups' that can all be completed with the same tool set.

These groups have to have no conflicts in the 'tool sets'. I.e. no two tools can occupy the same station. If a tool is used for more than one job it's characteristics (station,clearance,angle) all have to be identical. etc.

**I just have no idea how to do that sort of sorting to a dictionary in python**. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

also: there will be around 4-5 thousand jobs in the dictionary. Though the time it takes to sort isn't particularly crucial.

**EDIT:
Simple example (with only one tool characterstic) as I don't think I'm being clear:**

Job1 needs:

- Hammer - st: 2
- Screwdriver - st:4

Job2 needs

- Hammer - st: 2
- Nail gun - st: 6

Job3 needs:

- Hammer - st:2
- wrench - st: 4

Job 4 needs:

- wrench - st: 4
- Nail gun - st:6

Job 5 needs:

- screwdriver st: 4
- pillow st: 5

**Thus the program would output**

Jobs: 2, 3 and 4 can be done with:

- Hammer - st: 2
- wrench - st: 4
- Nail gun - st: 6

Job 1 and 5 can be done with:

- Hammer - st: 1
- screwdriver - st: 4
- pillow - st: 5

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a ready answer for this interesting problem, but my first thought was to look into **clustering**; maybe defining some sort of distance/similarity between jobs, based on the tools used, and playing with clustering rules until one satisfies your needs?

Comment: Cheers for the pointer. I'll have a look into clustering :)

Comment: I've been staring at your jobs grouping example for the last 10 min, and the way you grouped them doesn't seem to match the set of rules explained above... It is possible I am missing the point, but maybe because of your familiarity with the problem, you have omitted some of the rules/expertise used to segregate the jobs?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Where exactly is the conflict? 
The grouping of the example is mainly based around station 4 and how it necessitates two different groups. (Tools cannot occupy the same station). 

Background information: currently there is absolutely NO job grouping at all. 
I.e. The machine would be loaded with the Hammer and Screwdriver and then Job 1 would be completed. After which the nail gun would be loaded and Job 2 completed. 

Then the screwdriver would be removed and replaced with a wrench and job 3 would be completed. Etc. etc.\n 

As you can see it's highly inefficient.

Comment: Reblochon, as I understand it: the output is a set of station "setups" where each tool only occupies one station. There is a fixed number of stations (say, 3), and more tools than stations. All jobs must be handled by at least one of the setups, and the number of setups required should be minimized. A setup will handle a job if the stations contains a subset of the tools the job needs.

Comment: @johncip Exactly! The main aim is to try and get the number of tool changes (i.e. number of different toolsets) to a minimum so that the least amount of time is spent loading tools into the machine.

Comment: OK, I got it. I was fixating on the changes of tools inside a job, when the CNC head is reloaded on the fly, not between jobs. Thanks for the explanation. You'll maybe need two levels of optimization: (1) as you explained it, and (2) an optimal sequencing of the jobs from one group to another (if changing one tool at a time is more efficient than changing the whole set of tools on your machines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would approach the problem. This is based on your simple example though and may not make sense for more complicated setups.

Assuming a limited number of tools, take all combinations of tools (call them 'setups') and determine which jobs each setup can complete.

Then search for combinations of setups that can complete all jobs, starting with combinations of length 1, then increasing.

```
import itertools

num_stations = 3

tools = (
        ('hammer', 2),
        ('screwdriver', 4),
        ('nail gun', 6),
        ('wrench', 4),
        ('pillow', 5),
)

job_requirements = (
        (('hammer', 2), ('screwdriver', 4)),
        (('hammer', 2), ('nail gun', 6)),
        (('hammer', 2), ('wrench', 4)),
        (('wrench', 4), ('nail gun', 6)),
        (('screwdriver', 4), ('pillow', 5)),
)

def satisfies_job(tools, job):
    return all(tool in tools for tool in job)

setups = []
for comb in itertools.combinations(tools, num_stations):
    # store this setup if no tool conflicts
    if len(set(tool[1] for tool in comb)) == len(comb):
        setups.append(comb)

# check increasing numbers of combinations of setups until all jobs can be performed
for num_setups in range(1, len(setups)):
    for setups_comb in itertools.combinations(setups, num_setups):
        # check if all jobs can be completed with this combination of tool setups
        if all(any(satisfies_job(comb, job) for comb in setups_comb) for job in
                job_requirements):
            print 'found valid tool setup combination:'
            for comb in setups_comb:
                print comb
            exit(0)
```

Results:

```
found valid tool setup combination:
(('hammer', 2), ('nail gun', 6), ('wrench', 4))
(('hammer', 2), ('screwdriver', 4), ('pillow', 5))
```

This stores all combinations of tools in memory, so may use a lot of memory as number of tools increases. It could undoubtedly be optimised, but should provide a starting point.

**EDIT**

There's a bug in the above that requires setups containing `num_stations` of tools, so it fails for `num_stations = 5` as there is only one combination, but it has a conflict. To correct that issue, it should allow setups of *up to* `num_stations` tools:

```
# check increasing numbers of combinations of setups until all jobs can be performed
for num_setups in range(1, 1 + len(job_requirements)):
    print('check combinations of %d setups' % num_setups)
    setups = (c for c in chain(*(combinations(tools, i) for i in range(1, 1+num_stations)))
            if len(set(tool[1] for tool in c)) == len(c))
    for setups_comb in combinations(setups, num_setups):
        # check if all jobs can be completed with this combination of tool setups
        if all(any(satisfies_job(comb, job) for comb in setups_comb) for job in
                job_requirements):
            print 'found valid tool setup combination:'
            for comb in setups_comb:
                print comb
            exit(0)
```

This also removes the memory use problem by iterating over a generator for the setups.

Comment: That looks fantastic! Thank you so much for taking the time to write that. I haven't played with it yet but at the very least I have a smidgen of an idea of how to go about this now. 

Is there a special way to give reputation? As I'd certainly like to rep that answer. Upvoting your answer seemed logical?

Comment: @ashgetstazered thanks, happy to help. You can mark an answer as accepted if it solves your problem, but it's up to you if that is appropriate here. Let us know how you go with the full toolset - it might be too slow

Comment: ah cheers :) As of yet I'm quite a way off it all beautifully working so I'd like to keep peoples inputs coming in. 
With your solution is there a way to tie the jobs in with the toolsets? So when it gives it's solution sets, it can say what jobs you can do with them?

Comment: @ashgetstazered it doesn't store that information, but you can easily recalculate it (for a given `setup`): `[job for job in job_requirements if satisfies_job(setup, job)]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer, but this doesn't look like a sorting problem since the output isn't the same list of jobs (and even if it were, you can't sort a Python dict -- instead one might output a sorted list of key, value pairs). So I would recommend tagging it as "optimization" rather than sorting, probably "scheduling" as well.

In general, this is an optimization problem, but more specifically, I suspect it's an instance of job-shop scheduling:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling

I haven't worked with that class of problem, so I'm afraid I can't give you any pointers on how to model things, but it may be worth starting there.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I've updated the tags and will have a look at that link :)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to solve your problem with [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). However, I am still not able to, since you haven't specified your problem properly. Therefore, I will just give you a general answer:

The idea behind linear programming is, that you need to specify an arbitrary linear, multivariate cost-function and an arbitrary number of restrictions (usually inequalities, such as "sum of all tools in use at the same time <= 5, etc."). After you have specified your problem properly, you can use techniques like the simplex algorithm or the interior point method to get a solution that minimizes/maximizes your cost function and is feasible according to your restrictions (if such a solutions exists). You can even verify the optimum of your solution easily - even by hand (complementary slackness). If you need integer solutions (this problems are a bit harder) you can use techniques like branch-and-bound to get those. Linear programming is a well studied and flexible field of study and it can be easily applied to all kind of optimization problems.

Things that are still missing in your problem statement:

- What are the costs of change? Are they the same when switching between arbitrary tools, or is adding/removing different? Are there some constant base costs for each change (e.g. for stopping and resuming the machines)?
- Are there costs for operating with any of those tools, e.g. should you try to minimize the number of equipped tools in order to minimize their operation costs?
- How many tools can you equip at once? Can you equip all of them, or just a certain amount or just one of each type or a combination of those?
- Are there limits on the number of batches that can be done?
- Do the jobs take different amounts of time and are those times known in advance?
- ...

Comment: Yeah sorry, I understand that I probably left a bit out.  
Would it be possible to give an example how linear programming could solve the simple example?  
Given:  
Costs of change are equal for removing/adding.  
All tool changes are equal (this is not true for the complex example)
There is no cost of equipping/using a tool. (for the purpose of this program anyway).
can only equip 3 tools (for the simple example).
I don't understand the limit of batches. 
Jobs take an equal amount of time (this is not important though, all jobs need to be completed)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of parameters to the problem and some of them are stated (4-8 tools) but some of them aren't (how many stations, is there only one hammer). This may be able to be simplified by defining a "tool" as a "hammer at clearance=X and angle=Z" for example.

I would start by producing a reverse map of some kind. Either Toolset to job or Station/Tool to job.

Toolset to job mapping would allow you to say "for a given toolset, which jobs can I process". Adding a function to say if two toolsets are compatible (i.e. the same except for stations without a tool) and another to produce a combined toolset as the sum of two compatible toolsets. In your example, jobs 1 and 5 have compatible toolsets, as do jobs 2 and3 and the sum and 4. You can then process all the jobs in the set of compatible toolsets by mounting a combination of the compatible toolsets.

```
groups = {}
for job in jobs:
    x = ['________' for i in range(num_stations)]
    for tool in jobs[job]:
        x[jobs[job][tool][station]] = tool
    y = ','.join(x)
    if y not in groups:
        groups[y] = [job]
    else:
        groups[y].append(job)
```

Station to tool to job mapping would allow you to say "for this station if I mount that tool what jobs will that help with".

```
stations = []
for station in range(num_stat):
    stations.append({})
for job_name in sorted(jobs.keys()):
    for tool in sorted(jobs[job_name].keys()):
        pos = jobs[job_name][tool][station]
        if tool not in stations[pos]:
            stations[pos][tool] = set()
        stations[pos][tool].add(job_name)
```

Anyhow, here's a bit of a hack-together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: tabstop=8  softtabstop=4  shiftwidth=4  nocindent  smartindent
import random
import traceback, sys
Verbose = False
random.seed(4)
num_loops = 500  # Number of times to run the job-scheduling loop
num_stat =  6   # Number of stations where tool can be loaded
min_tools = 2   # lowest tool count for a job
max_tools = 4   # highest tool count for a job
num_posts = 3   # Number of stations a tool can be mounted
num_jobs = 5000  # Number of simulated jobs
num_tools = 6  # Number of different tool/offset/angle combinations

# Setup the tools database
# tool_names is a list of the names of the available tools (with offset and angle)
# tools is a map giving a list of positions where the tool can be loaded
tool_names = sorted(['tool%03d' % idx for idx in range(num_tools)])
tool_fmap = {}
tool_rmap = {}
for tool in tool_names:
    tool_fmap[tool] = sorted(random.sample(xrange(num_stat), num_posts))
    for pos in tool_fmap[tool]:
        if pos not in tool_rmap:
            tool_rmap[pos] = set()
        tool_rmap[pos].add(tool)

for tool in sorted(tool_fmap.keys()):
    print "%-8s" % tool, sorted(tool_fmap[tool])
for pos in sorted(tool_rmap.keys()):
    print "%2d" % pos, sorted(tool_rmap[pos])

# Build the jobs and stations database
def make_jobs_database():
    jobs = {}
    distro = [0 for i in range(num_stat + 1)]
    short_count = [0 for i in range(num_stat + 1)]
    for job_num in range(num_jobs):
        job_name = "job%04d" % job_num
        jobs[job_name] = {}
        num_tools_in_job = random.randrange(min_tools, max_tools + 1)
        t_list = random.sample(tool_names, num_stat)
        available_positions = range(num_stat)
        num_posns_allocated = 0
        for tool in t_list:
            possible_positions = [x for x in tool_fmap[tool] if x in available_positions]
            if len(possible_positions) == 0:
                continue
            jobs[job_name][tool] = random.choice(possible_positions)
            available_positions.remove(jobs[job_name][tool])
            num_posns_allocated += 1
            if num_posns_allocated >= num_tools_in_job:
                break
        if len(jobs[job_name].keys()) < num_tools_in_job:
            short_count[len(jobs[job_name].keys())] += 1
        distro[len(jobs[job_name].keys())] += 1
    print "Shorts:", short_count
    for idx, cnt in enumerate(distro):
        print "Jobs with %d tools = %d" % (idx, distro[idx])
    return jobs

def make_station_database(jobs):
    stations = []
    for station in range(num_stat):
        stations.append({})
    for job_name in sorted(jobs.keys()):
        for tool in sorted(jobs[job_name].keys()):
            pos = jobs[job_name][tool]
            if tool not in stations[pos]:
                stations[pos][tool] = set()
            stations[pos][tool].add(job_name)
    return stations

def make_group_database(jobs):
    groups = {}
    for job_name in sorted(jobs.keys()):
        x = ['_______' for i in range(num_stat)]
        for tool in sorted(jobs[job_name].keys()):
            pos = jobs[job_name][tool]
            x[pos] = tool
        z = ",".join(x)
        if z not in groups:
            groups[z] = []
        groups[z].append(job_name)
    return groups

def show_jobs_database(jobs):
    print "Jobs Database:"
    for job_name in sorted(jobs.keys()):
        x = ['_______' for i in range(num_stat)]
        for tool in sorted(jobs[job_name].keys()):
            pos = jobs[job_name][tool]
            x[pos] = tool
        z = ",".join(x)
        print job_name, z

def show_station_database(stations):
    print "Station Database:"
    for idx, stat in enumerate(stations):
        print idx
        for tool in sorted(stat.keys()):
            print '  ', tool, sorted(stat[tool])

def show_group_database(groups):
    print "Groups Database:"
    for group in sorted(groups.keys()):
        print group, groups[group]

def prune_station_database(stations, done_jobs):
    for pos in range(num_stat):
        empty_tools = []
        for tool in stations[pos]:
            stations[pos][tool].difference_update(done_jobs)
            if len(stations[pos][tool]) == 0:
                empty_tools.append(tool)
        for tool in empty_tools:
            del stations[pos][tool]

def make_selection(stations, all_possible_jobs):
    global tools_used, posns_used
    selections = []
    tools_used = {}
    posns_used = {}
    possible_jobs = all_possible_jobs.copy()
    for i in range(num_stat): # select a station to populate
        target_posn = None
        target_tool = None
        target_len = 0
        for pos in range(num_stat): # inspect each station
            if pos in posns_used:
                continue
            key_len = 0
            key_pos = None
            key_tool = None
            for tool in stations[pos]: # inspect each tool at this station
                if tool in tools_used:
                    continue
                new_len = len(possible_jobs.intersection(stations[pos][tool]))
                if new_len > key_len:
                    key_len = new_len
                    key_pos = pos
                    key_tool = tool
            if key_len > target_len:
                target_len = key_len
                target_posn = key_pos
                target_tool = key_tool
        if target_tool is not None:
            tools_used[target_tool] = target_posn
        if target_posn is not None:
            posns_used[target_posn] = target_tool
            possible_jobs.intersection_update(stations[target_posn][target_tool])
            selections.append((target_posn, target_tool))
        if Verbose:
            print "Jobs:", len(possible_jobs), sorted(list(possible_jobs))
    if not Verbose: # print it at least once
        print "Jobs:", len(possible_jobs), sorted(list(possible_jobs))
    # We have all the tools we need, see if there are more we can use
    for pos in range(num_stat):
        extra_jobs = 0
        best_tool = None
        if pos not in posns_used:
            new_posns = {pos:None}
            for p in posns_used:
                new_posns[p] = posns_used[p]
            for tool in stations[pos]:
                if tool in tools_used:
                    continue
                key_count = 0
                new_posns[pos] = tool
                for job in stations[pos][tool]:
                    if job_is_ok(job, None, new_posns):
                        key_count += 1
                if key_count > extra_jobs:
                    extra_jobs = key_count
                    best_tool = tool
            tools_used[best_tool] = pos
            posns_used[pos] = best_tool
            selections.append((pos, best_tool))
    print "Tools:", tools_used
    print "Stations:", posns_used
    print "Selections:", selections

def toolset_compatible(x, y):
    if len(x) != len(y):
        return False
    for idx in range(len(x)):
        if x[idx] == y[idx]:
            continue
        if x[idx] == '' and y[idx] not in x:
            continue
        if y[idx] == '' and x[idx] not in y:
            continue
        return False
    if Verbose:
        print "Compatible:"
        print x
        print y
    return True

def toolset_combine(x, y):
    z = []
    for idx, xval in enumerate(x):
        if xval == '':
            z.append(y[idx])
        else:
            z.append(xval)
    if Verbose:
        print "Combined:"
        print x
        print y
        print z
    return z

def job_is_ok(job, tools_used, posns_used):
    for tool in jobs[job]:
        pos = jobs[job][tool]
        if pos not in posns_used:
            pass
        elif posns_used[pos] != tool:
            return False
    return True

def job_is_on(job, tools_used):
    for tool in jobs[job]:
        pos = jobs[job][tool]
        if tool not in tools_used:
            return False
        if tools_used[tool] != pos:
            return False
    return True

def use_stations(stations):
    all_possible_jobs = set(jobs.keys())
    try:
        for run in range(num_loops):
            make_selection(stations, all_possible_jobs)
            jobs_on = set()
            for job in all_possible_jobs:
                if job_is_on(job, tools_used):
                    jobs_on.add(job)
            print "JobsOn:", len(jobs_on), sorted(jobs_on)
            prune_station_database(stations, jobs_on)
            count_before = len(all_possible_jobs)
            all_possible_jobs.difference_update(set(jobs_on))
            count_after = len(all_possible_jobs)
            print "Counts: run = %d, before = %d, after = %d" % (run + 1, count_before, count_after)
            if count_before == count_after:
                break
            if count_after == 0:
                break
    except Exception, err:
        print traceback.format_exc()
        print "Tools:", tools_used
        print "Stations:", posns_used
    show_station_database(stations)

def use_groups(groups):
    all_possible_jobs = set(jobs.keys())
    try:
        for run in range(num_loops):
            selected_group = None
            group_len = 0
            for group in groups.keys():
                if len(groups[group]) > group_len:
                    group_len = len(groups[group])
                    selected_group = group
            if Verbose:
                print "Selected:", selected_group, groups[selected_group]
            selected_groups = [selected_group]
            toolset = [x.strip('_') for x in selected_group.split(',')]
            for group in groups.keys():
                if group in selected_groups:
                    continue
                new_toolset = [x.strip('_') for x in group.split(',')]
                if toolset_compatible(toolset, new_toolset):
                    toolset = toolset_combine(toolset, new_toolset)
                    selected_groups.append(group)
            jobs_on = set()
            tools_used = {}
            for idx, tool in enumerate(toolset):
                if tool != '':
                    tools_used[tool] = idx
            print "Tools:", tools_used
            for job in all_possible_jobs:
                if job_is_on(job, tools_used):
                    jobs_on.add(job)
            print "JobsOn:", len(jobs_on), sorted(jobs_on)
            for group in selected_groups:
                if group in groups:
                    del groups[group]
            count_before = len(all_possible_jobs)
            all_possible_jobs.difference_update(set(jobs_on))
            count_after = len(all_possible_jobs)
            print "Counts: run = %d, before = %d, after = %d" % (run + 1, count_before, count_after)
            if count_before == count_after:
                break
            if count_after == 0:
                break
    except Exception, err:
        print traceback.format_exc()
        print "Tools:", tools_used
        print "Selected:", selected_groups
    show_group_database(groups)

def main_program():
    global jobs, stations, groups
    jobs = make_jobs_database()
    if Verbose:
        show_jobs_database(jobs)
    groups = make_group_database(jobs)
    if Verbose:
        show_group_database(groups)
    stations = make_station_database(jobs)
    if Verbose:
        show_station_database(stations)
    if True:
        use_groups(groups)
    else:
        use_stations(stations)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import cProfile
    cProfile.run('main_program()')
```

You can try the two alternative methods by changing the True to False at the bottom of the main_program. You can adjust the major parameters at the top. You can print a lot of output by setting verbose to true at the top. It takes a few seconds to run, a lot of which is building the job database.

Comment: Revisiting this now when I'm older, wiser and (slightly) more informed: this is a great way of attacking the problem! 

The only problem I could see is with scalability. The implementation that I was working on had something in the range of 2000-4000 jobs, each with 10-20 tools. Though I suppose you could generate the maps once, and then just optimise daily schedules, and only remake the maps when a new job was added or an existing one was modified.

Comment: The way I did use mapping in a sense, it was basically incremental toolset mapping. It started off with a job and then iterated through other jobs and saw if they were compatible or not, adding them and then using their total toolset to then check against other jobs. etc. etc.

I've never known how optimal it was. 

Do you work in optimisation/algorithm development by any chance?